# Embedding WebBrowser in Custom pane using Excel-DNA

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I am trying to embed a browser in Custom task pane of excel using excel DNA but I am getting exception every time. I have modified the Excel dna sample shown [here](https://github.com/KevinT/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/CustomTaskPane.dna) to use `WebBrowser` control from Windows Forms instead of `Label`

```
TheLabel = new WebBrowser{ };
                //TheLabel.Text = "My First CTP!";
                TheLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20);
                TheLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 60);
                TheLabel.Navigate(new Uri("www.rbs.com"));
                Controls.Add(TheLabel);
```

This is giving me exception, Please can anybody help in resolving this issue

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your response , I am able to resolve the issue , this issue came as browser accept only URI starting with "http" whereas I was giving "www". but one thing I am not sure as to why catch block was not getting hit on this statement.below statement was immediately stopping the program and on Excel I was getting a exception "Target invocation failed due to exception".                   CustomTaskPaneFactory.CreateCustomTaskPane(typeof (MyUserControl), "My Super Task Pane");

Comment: I added the usercontrol in toolbox and then drag and drop it on my windows form which immediately thrown error that it has a invalid uri and I should use "http" for uri's which was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

issue got resolved , issue was that the uri was incorrect , it should start with 'http' instead of 'www ' but since the program itself was closing without going to catch block it was difficult to investigate.

I added the user control in Toolbox and then drag and drop it on my windows form which has given me perfect reason of why my code was failing.